# How to hide the vertical & horizontall scroll bar from the page using Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

I know it is repetitive question but problem remained unsolved tried various approaches show in various sites but in chrome the scroll bar is hiding and it is working fine but in Mozilla Firefox it is displaying the scroll bar even i applied the hidden properties for -moz.

below is my code :

```
.scroll-box {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 1rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

// this is for google
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

for Firefox i tried this from documentation then also it is displaying the scroll bar

```
overflow-y: -moz-hidden-hidden
```

below is the url sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usy73w

[image: Scroll bar displaying in firefox]

Comment: Do you have an example? I've tried it and it works just fine

Comment: the above which i posted is from example only

Comment: @JordanQuartermain updated the code with url please check

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code IN FIREFOX and it works. (The code is the one you have provided).

Perhaps, try resetting your browser settings on firefox and see if that helps.

Also, I believe you are trying to hide the horizontal scrollbar. If that is not the case, and you are trying to hide the vertical scrollbar, then simply switch the overflow x and y properties.

Comment: May i ask? What are you trying to hide? The vertical scroll bar or the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: i am trying for vertical scroll bar & if i switch those overall scroll is not working

Comment: If you are trying to hide the vertical scroll bar then change overflow-y to hidden. If you want to keep the horizontal scroll bar, then change overflow-x to scroll and if not, then keep it the same.

Comment: tried that approach after implementing that only scroll stopped working

Answer (score -1):

I've tested the code in codepen and it works as expected.

Edited after further investigation:
First off, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to hide, the horizontal scrollbar, the vertical scrollbar, or both.

If you want to hide both, `overflow:hidden` should do the trick. I've interpreted your question as wanting to hide the vertical scrollbar. In this case, it is actually working properly in Firefox (based on your code) and is hiding in Chrome because of your `-webkit-scrollbar` css property.

Comment: have you tested the code bcoz it is still showing the scrollbar in the firefox please once check

Comment: I have updated the pen to have a wider child div and confirmed in Firefox and Chrome that only the vertical scrollbar is showing. What version of FF are you using?

Comment: i am using firefox 61 version and vertical scrollbar only it doesnt have to show